# C# - add multiple users into list field with multi selection option

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I have a Sharepoint list called AproverList where ApproverName2 field is "Person or Group" type with multiple selection option

[image]

[image]

This is the code I'm using, but it allows me to enter only one user into the field ApproverName2.
Do you know how to achieve the insertion of multiple users into this multi selection field?

```
        using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(siteUri.ToString(), accessToken))
        {
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            try
            {
                List targetList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("ApproverList");

                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                ListItem newListItem = targetList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                newListItem["ApproverId"] = "1";
                newListItem["Title"] = "GBO";
                newListItem["ApproverName2"] = web.EnsureUser("jsamakm");
                newListItem.Update();

                clientContext.Load(newListItem);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `SPFieldUserValueCollection` to set multiple person / group field

```
 SPFieldUserValueCollection usercollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
```

This is a similar example

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection value = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
value.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, user1.ID, user1.Name)));
value.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, user2.ID, user2.Name)));

objItem["name"] = value;
objItem.Update();
```

- Check Similar thread [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426660/how-to-insert-data-in-person-or-group-field-using-vs2010/8428774#8428774)
- Check the [similar full code](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/multiple-user-insertion-in-sharepoint-list/)